# Why is this simple program exercise not returning False?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement

Write a function `is_better_than_avg(students, pos)`, that takes two arguments `students` is the list of all students' dictionaries position is an integer - position of the student in the list we want to check. Checking works like this - count the average of all grades in the school (upper cell) compare the value to the student's average. Return `True` if the student has an avg greater than the school avg, otherwise, return `False`.

I don't know why the second execution of the program says `True` instead of `False`.

```
# Function for testing purposes
def test(got, expected):
  if got == expected:
    prefix = ' OK '
  else:
    prefix = "  Something's wrong  "
  print(prefix,' got:',repr(got),'expected:',repr(expected))
list_of_students = []
list_of_students.append(kosma) # appending the student k1sma

def is_passed(student_dict):
  return avg(student_dict)>=3.0
  
def school_avg(students):
  all = 0
  licznik = 0
  for a in students:
    all = all + avg(a)  #dodaje średnią sprawdzanego studenta do 'all'
    licznik = licznik + 1 #dodaje 1 do liczniku

  return all / licznik

list_of_students.append({
    "username": "mikub",
    "age":24,
    "is_blocked": False,
    "grades": [5,5,5,5]
})

list_of_students.append({
    "username": "ewa",
    "age":24,
    "is_blocked": False,
    "grades": [1,3,3,2,1,1,1,1,1,1]
})

list_of_students.append({
    "username": "robert",
    "age":24,
    "is_blocked": False,
    "grades": [5,5,5,5,5,1]
})
list_of_students.append({
    "username": "radek",
    "age":24,
    "is_blocked": False,
    "grades": [1,3,3,2,5,5,5]
})

list_of_students.append({
    "username": "kasia",
    "age":24,
    "is_blocked": False,
    "grades": [5,5,5,1]
})

list_of_students.append({
    "username": "kasia",
    "age":24,
    "is_blocked": False,
    "grades": [5,1,1,1,1,5,1]
})
list_of_students.append({
    "username": "jola",
    "age":24,
    "is_blocked": False,
    "grades": [5,4,5,5,5,4]
})

#this is the important part

def is_better_than_avg(students,pos):
  for pos in students:
    if avg(pos) > school_avg(students):
      return True
    elif avg(pos) < school_avg(students):
      return False

test(is_better_than_avg(list_of_students,0),True) #returns True as it should
test(is_better_than_avg(list_of_students,6),False) #idk why this returns True as well
```

Comment: `kosma` and `avg` are not defined, please fix it

Comment: You compute the avg of grade for one, and the avg of all grades together ? Or avg of each avg ?

Comment: school average is 3.5 and average of selected student is 5

Comment: `jola` has an average of 4.6, that is higher than school avg 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should change the  `is_better_than_avg`   function like this :

```
def is_better_than_avg(students,pos):
    student = students[pos]
    if avg(student) > school_avg(students):
        return True
    elif avg(student) < school_avg(students):
        return False
```

Comment: YES, thank you so much! I understand that I had to also include the dictionary since pos is just a number.